# PyQt QScrollArea no scrollarea

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I have

```
class View(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(View,self).__init__()

        self.cropLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.ogpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        fileName = r'C:/Users/user11.HPO-SAMAT/Pictures/Lake.jpg'
        image = QtGui.QImage(fileName)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.adjustSize()
```

and then I call this class:

```
class Viewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.view = View()
        self.scroller = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scroller.setWidget(self.view)
        self.scroller.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroller.adjustSize()
```

But QScrollArea does not seem to work (noscrollbar though the image is visible and I can expand QMainWindows to see it entirely)
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand so they put several labels inside View, if we remove the labels that are other we get what you want.

```
class View(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(View,self).__init__(parent)
        fileName = "/home/qhipa/Pictures/1475777628875.jpg"
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


class Viewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.view = View(self)
        self.scroller = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroller)
        self.scroller.setWidget(self.view)
        self.scroller.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroller.adjustSize()
```

[image]

Instead if you want to get several labels, it is better that the View class inherits from QWidget.

```
class View(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(View,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

        self.cropLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.cropLabel)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("/home/qhipa/Pictures/1475777628875.jpg")
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.adjustSize()
```

Comment: Hi yes you're right thanks a lot. I missunderstood from which class the the View should inherits and the way to implement its content